# LaTeX3 - An equivalent of `\def`?

Tags: latex3

In the MWE below, I use `\def\path{numworks/\int_use:N \l__test_this_step_int.png}` and `\includegraphics[scale = #3]{\path}`.

Can I avoid the use `\def` for a "pure" LaTeX3 coding style?

Note: the next step of my code will be to replace `?` by the actual step counter in the argument `numworks/?.png` given by the user.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}


\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l__test_max_step_int
\int_new:N \l__test_this_step_int

\DeclareDocumentCommand\screensteps{vvv}{
    \int_set:Nn \l__test_max_step_int{#1}
    \int_set:Nn \l__test_this_step_int{0}
    
% Lets' print the material...
    \int_do_while:nn {\l__test_this_step_int < \l__test_max_step_int} {
        \int_gincr:N \l__test_this_step_int
        
        \int_if_odd:nTF { \l__test_this_step_int } {
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \centering
        }{
                \columnbreak
        }
            
                \par\emph{Étape \ \int_use:N \l__test_this_step_int.}
        
                \par\smallskip
                
                %%%%%%%%%%%%     HERE
                \def\path{numworks/\int_use:N \l__test_this_step_int.png}
                %%%%%%%%%%%%     HERE
                \includegraphics[scale = #3]{\path}

        \int_if_even:nT{ \l__test_this_step_int } {
            \end{multicols} 
        }
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\screensteps{6}{numworks/?.png}{.6}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\def` is very generic, so it depends a lot on what you want to do.  If you want `\def` as in “define a command”, then you want `\cs_new(_protected):Npn`.  If you want `\def` as in “store some data”, then you want `\tl_set:Nn`.  Here you want to store a path to an image, so definitely the latter.  Besides, a path to an image can be thought more specifically as a string, so you can use `\str_set:Nn`.

In the code below I used `\str_set:Nx` so that any user macros in the argument are expanded, and already added `\str_replace_all:Nnn` to replace all `?` by the current step number.  Since you just want to unconditionally loop from 1 to `#1`, you can use `\int_step_inline:nn` rather than compare the step number and increase the counter each time.  If you use `\int_step_inline:nn`, then you have the current loop index available as `##1` in the inline code.

The example below tries to include `numworks/1.png` though `numworks/6.png` (and fails because I don't have those files :)

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \l__test_path_str
\DeclareDocumentCommand \screensteps {mmm}
  {
    \int_step_inline:nn {#1}
      {
        \int_if_odd:nTF {##1}
          {
            \begin{multicols}{2}
              \centering
          }
          { \columnbreak }
        \par \emph {Étape ~ ##1 . }
        \par \smallskip
        \str_set:Nx \l__test_path_str {#2}
        \str_replace_all:Nnn \l__test_path_str { ? } {##1}
        \includegraphics[scale = #3]{\l__test_path_str}
        \int_if_even:nT {##1}
          { \end{multicols} }
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\screensteps{6}{numworks/?.png}{.6}
\end{document}
```

**Screenshot added by projetmbc**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for this shorter and easier-to-read code. I am thinking of the time needed to do the same thing in pure TeX even if I have definitely stop to use this language.

Comment: @projetmbc Things like loops are actually rather easy to write in pure TeX, but things like `\str_replace_all:Nnn` are really a pain to reimplement.  Also note that in the code I replaced the `v` arguments by `m` because you are not really using verbatim there.

Comment: Yes you're right.